# onclick button multiple textbox read only property should change in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

on click the button `edit` the above `textbox` property readonly must disable.

How can i do this

My script

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName("text").readOnly = "false";
    }
</script>
```

in JSP page HTML controls

```
<input type="text" name="te" value="1" readonly/>
<input type="text" name="val" value="3" readonly/>
<input type="text" name="gir" value="5" readonly/>
<input type="text" name="sad" value="13" readonly/>

<input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of objects and `text` is not a tag type. Change it as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  for(var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length-1;i++)
     document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
}
```

Working Fiddle:   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kdQp/)